# How to validate the selected data based on the column name using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Need to select few records on the table and if any of the selected records have firstname as `Superman` need to show alert message, Tried below code, please help me the issue...

```
const verifyRecords = this.persons
        .filter(person => person.checked)
        .filter(person => ["Superman"].includes(this.persons.firstame));

        alert(JSON.stringify(verifyRecords));
    
      if (verifyRecords.length > 0) {
         verifyRecords.forEach(result =>
          alert(`Please select Valid data` ));
          return false;
      }else{
        alert("Selected data is valid");
      }
  }
```

[Demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/avoid-disable-checkboxes-check-quiqyj)

Comment: There is a verify button on the top left, so the alert message have to shown after clicking this button or as soon as you select "Superman"?

Comment: Click on verify button to validate the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the spelling `this.persons.firstame`.

I changed to `person.firstName` and it showing the alert message

```js
const verifyRecords = this.persons
        .filter(person => person.checked)
        .filter(person => ["Superman"].includes(person.firstName));

        alert(JSON.stringify(verifyRecords));
```

The output showing is :

[image: Output Alert Message after checking superman]

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change the line:

```
        .filter(person => ["Superman"].includes(this.persons.firstame));
```

to:

```
        .filter(person => "Superman" == person.firstName);
```